SSLHandshakeException in Password Recovery System Using JavaMail with JSP Project on Tomcat 9
I'm working on a Java JSP project deployed on Tomcat 9 with a PostgreSQL database for data storage. A critical part of this system is the password recovery functionality, which is implemented using the JavaMail API to send recovery emails to users. However, I am facing persistent issues with the email-sending feature due to SSL handshake errors.
Here is a breakdown of my project setup:
Project Setup:
Java Version: OpenJDK 21.0.4 LTS (Temurin)
openjdk version "21.0.4" 2024-07-16 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Temurin-21.0.4+7 (build 21.0.4+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Temurin-21.0.4+7 (build 21.0.4+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)


JSP and Java Servlets: Used for frontend and backend logic.

Server: Tomcat 9, running on Windows, with the following configurations:

JRE Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\jre
JDK Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_80
Tomcat Path: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0
Catalina Config: C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\conf\Catalina


Database: PostgreSQL 42.2.29 driver (PostgreSQL JDBC)


Main Issue: The password recovery system relies on sending emails via JavaMail, but I keep getting an SSL handshake error whenever the system tries to send an email. Below is the full error message:
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeContext.<init>(HandshakeContext.java:171)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshakeContext.<init>(ClientHandshakeContext.java:101)
    at sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.kickstart(TransportContext.java:238)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:394)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:373)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.configureSSLSocket(SocketFetcher.java:549)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:354)
    at com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:237)
    at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.openServer(SMTPTransport.java:1927)

This issue appears whenever the system tries to connect to the email server via SSL to send the recovery emails.
Libraries Used (JARs):

PostgreSQL JDBC (postgresql-42.2.29.jre7.jar)
Bcrypt (jbcrypt-0.4.jar)
JavaMail API (mail-1.4.7.jar, smtp-1.6.2.jar, javax.activation.jar)
Security Policies (US_export_policy.jar, local_policy.jar)

RECOVERY_ACCOUNT.JSP
// THIS IS THE MAIN CODE THAT IS SENDING EMAILS (RECOVERY_ACCOUNT.JSP)

    // Database connection configurations
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/bibliotech";
    String user = "postgres";
    String password = "admin";
    
    String email = request.getParameter("email");
    String passwordHash = null;
    
    try {
        // Connect to the database
        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
        enter code here
        // Query to check if the email exists
        String query = "SELECT password_hash FROM USERS WHERE email = ?";
        PreparedStatement ps`enter code here`tmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setString(1, email);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
    
        if (rs.next()) {
            passwordHash = rs.getString("password_hash");  // Retrieve the password hash
        } else {
            out.println("<script>alert('Email not found!'); window.location.href = 'recovery.jsp';</script>");
        }
    
        rs.close();
        pstmt.close();
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
    // If the password hash was found, send an email to the user
    if (passwordHash != null) {
        // JavaMail configurations
        String host = "smtp.gmail.com";  // Using Gmail as an example
        String from = "bibliotechproject@gmail.com"; // Your email
        String appPassword = "iodz fnwh idsg wmpo";  // Use a Gmail app password
        String to = email;
        String subject = "Password Recovery - Bibliotech";
    
        // Email content with HTML
        String messageText = 
        "<div style='font-family: Arial, sans-serif; padding: 20px; background-color: #f4f4f4;'>"
            + "<center>"
                + "<img src='https://iili.io/dPzedMX.png' alt='Account Recovery' style='width: 100%; max-width: 600px; height: auto;'>"
                + "<div style='background-color: #ffffff; padding: 20px; border-radius: 8px; max-width: 600px; text-align: left;'>"
                    + "<h2 style='color: #333;'>Account Recovery</h2>"
                    + "<p style='color: #555;'>Hello,</p>"
                    + "<p style='color: #555;'>We received a request to recover the password for your account. Here are your login details:</p>"
                    + "<p style='font-weight: bold; color: #333;'>Email: " + email + "</p>"
                    + "<p style='font-weight: bold; color: #333;'>Password: " + passwordHash + "</p>"
                    + "<p style='color: #555;'>If you did not make this request, please ignore this email.</p>"
                    + "<p style='color: #555;'>Sincerely, https://prod.liveshare.vsengsaas.visualstudio.com/join?01A2BDE3A14A18BC1D1E0892E16E13D31189</p>"
                    + "<p style='color: #333; font-weight: bold;'>Support Team - Bibliotech</p>"
                + "</div>"
            + "</center>"
        + "</div>";
    
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", host);
        props.put("mail.smtp.user", from);
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", appPassword);
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
        props.put("mail.debug", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    
        Session mailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, null);
        MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(mailSession);
    
        try {
            message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
    
            message.setSubject(subject);
            message.setContent(messageText, "text/html");
    
            Transport transport = mailSession.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.connect(host, from, appPassword);
            transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients());
            transport.close();
    
            response.sendRedirect("send_success.jsp");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

I added these libraries

US_export_policy.jar
bcrypt-0.4.1.jar
bytes-0.4.6.jar
javax.activation.jar
jbcrypt-0.4.jar
local_policy.jar
mail-1.4.7.jar
postgresql-42.2.29.jre7.jar
smtp-1.6.2.jar

What I've Tried:
Ensured that the correct SSL protocols are enabled on the server and in my JavaMail configuration.
Tried updating the JavaMail library to resolve potential SSL protocol mismatches.
Looked at the order of the JARs in the lib folder to check for conflicting libraries.
Remaining Questions:
Is the SSL handshake error related to my Java 21 version, or is it a misconfiguration in the JavaMail or Tomcat server?
Could the issue stem from older versions of JavaMail or other JAR files causing conflicts with SSL protocols?
Has anyone encountered similar issues when using JavaMail for password recovery in a JSP project? How did you solve the SSL handshake problem?
I'd appreciate any advice on how to resolve this, especially regarding SSL configuration with JavaMail. If it's a matter of JAR versions, what would be the correct versions and ordering of these libraries?
Thanks in advance for any insights!
One day at the educational institution where I am carrying out this project, sending emails simply worked, without me needing to change anything, I just arrived, turned on the computer and everything worked, I believed it was the Java configuration installed on that machine, but in the the other day when I tested again on that same machine, it gave me an error again when sending emails.

You should add which TLS libraries are in use on the mail server and their version. Try to figure out the protocols allowed on both systems.

(1) Your Tomcat Run Time (Tomcat 9.0, JRE 1.7.0 , JDK 1.7.0) (2) But Your Project Setup (JDK 21.0.4) ? (3) In 2024, I will use JDK 11 with Tomcat 9.x. (4) Send Mail ? (a) SMTP , (b) SMTP  with StartTLS  (c) SMTP with SSL, (5) you get SSL handshake errors. (b) or (c) , you don't provide more code example.

(1) ADD props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true"); , Enable TLS encryption (2) REMOVE props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", "true"); (3) Port 587 is for StartTLS.

It worked my friend, thank you very much.

Removed and merged it into the question.
